# Phonegap upload request is empty

Tags: php, cordova

I'm developping a small application in phonegap, and the last feature, the upload, just block me.

```
function uploadFile() {

var options = new FileUploadOptions();

options.fileKey = 'video';
options.fileName = data.title;
options.mimeType = 'video/mp4';
options.httpMethod = 'POST';

var ft = new FileTransfer();
var path = data.mediaItem.fullPath;
var uploadURL = data.pushURL;
var name = data.title;

ft.upload(path,
    uploadURL,
function (result) {
    console.log(result.response + ' ' + result.responseCode);
},
function (error) {
    console.log('Error uploading file ' + error.source + ' ' + error.target + ': ' + error.code + ' ' + error.http_status);
},
options);
```

}

```
<?php
file_put_contents('logs.txt', print_r($_FILES));
print_r($_FILES);
$target_dir = "video/";
$target_file = $target_dir . "video";
$uploadOk = 1;
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been       uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";

}
}
?>
```

My upload request is received by the server (response code is 200), but my request is empty, and then my server throw me an error

I scratch my head since 1 week on this bug, and I can't resolve it.

Comment: I think the issue might be with your target file/location not resolving nor having an extension. Try changing this in your PHP code and then see if the error changes: `$target_file = $target_dir .'/'."video".'/'.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];`

Answer (score 0):

This line set the name to expecto on the server

```
 options.fileKey = 'video';
```

But you try to get it with

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]
```

change the fileKey from `'video'` to `'fileToUpload'` or the `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]` to `$_FILES["video"]`

Answer (score 0):

Already tried the two, but I finally found the solution.

U wanna laugh ? My modification of POST_MAX_SIZE in php.ini wasn't take in consideration, I had to do it again !

But really guys, thanks for your answers :)